# One external CSS file for 3 separate projects

Tags: css, websphere

I am currently working on 3 different projects with the same CSS/layout. As much as possible, I would want to only utilize 1 CSS file for all 3 projects to avoid copy pasting on 3 different and separate CSS files. These 3 projects are currently being deployed in Websphere. How should I approach this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upload your CSS file on one of the 3 projects and use the same href on all 3 projects

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yoursite.com/style.css">
```

Comment: Is it practical to create a separate web application just for globally used CSS and Javascript? As much as possible, I would want these projects to work independently and with this approach, it's not feasible.

Comment: I'd modify that by suggesting you might not even put it in a WebSphere project at all, but just an external, static URL. It's usually recommended that you have an HTTP Server and/or Proxy in front of WAS, so deploying common, static files there is trivial to do.